# tensorflow.python.eager.polymorphic_function No module error on imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have tried checking around for the solution for this error but all solutions I have found are not working. I am requesting for more assistance. I have this tensorflow error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\lmumelo\Documents\GitHub\NAR_Tensorflow_OD\scripts\modelling\NAR Object Detection Project.ipynb Cell 3 in <cell line: 25>()
     20 #from tflite_model_maker import model_spec
     21 #from tflite_model_maker import object_detector
     23 sys.path.append("..")
---> 25 from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
     26 from object_detection.utils import dataset_util, label_map_util, config_util
     27 from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2

File c:\Users\lmumelo\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py:39, in <module>
     37 from six.moves import range
     38 from six.moves import zip
---> 39 import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
     41 from object_detection.core import keypoint_ops
     42 from object_detection.core import standard_fields as fields

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py:92, in <module>
     90 from tensorflow.python.eager.backprop import GradientTape
     91 from tensorflow.python.eager.context import executing_eagerly
---> 92 from tensorflow.python.eager.polymorphic_function.polymorphic_function import function
     93 from tensorflow.python.framework.constant_op import constant
     94 from tensorflow.python.framework.device_spec import DeviceSpecV2 as DeviceSpec

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.eager.polymorphic_function'
```

The error is being generated from this imports

```
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util, label_map_util, config_util
from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops
from object_detection.protos import pipeline_pb2
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
from google.protobuf import text_format

import tensorflow as tf
```

And here is a list of installed packages

```
tb-nightly                    2.11.0a20221023
tensorboard                   2.10.1
tensorboard-data-server       0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit        1.8.0
tensorflow                    2.5.0
tensorflow-addons             0.18.0
tensorflow-datasets           4.7.0
tensorflow-estimator          2.5.0
tensorflow-hub                0.12.0
tensorflow-io                 0.27.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.27.0
tensorflow-metadata           1.10.0
tensorflow-model-optimization 0.7.3
tensorflow-text               2.10.0
termcolor                     1.1.0
terminado                     0.13.1
testpath                      0.6.0
text-unidecode                1.3
tf-estimator-nightly          2.12.0.dev2022102308
tf-models-official            2.10.0
tf-nightly                    2.12.0.dev20221023
tf_nightly_intel              2.12.0.dev20221023
```

I have tried

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow --upgrade
```

But this solutions are not working. Anyone who has ever experienced this error and solved it. **NOTE** that I am using anaconda environment to develop this tensorflow model and all packages are installed in that environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is easy to backward compatibilities try searching for version compatibilities and checkout from this website [TFLite Authoring Tool][1] they had the same problem and me testing it on the same from Git.

I am testing and found that the update link is targeting the incorrect path where I am using AMD. ( Prepending update )

```
platform_machine != "arm64" or platform_system != "Darwin", 
but you have tensorflow 2.10.0 which is incompatible.
```

Still building the rest of the package and trying to complied it to simulate following your question but the only thing I found is the miss attached link to target now.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Python310\\object_detection')

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
print(np.__version__)
print(tf.__version__)

from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util

# from object_detection.protos import pipeline_pb2
# from object_detection.builders import model_builder
# from object_detection.utils import dataset_util, label_map_util, config_util
# from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2


from google.protobuf import text_format

import tensorflow_models as tfm
```

Answer (score 0):

In CMD command line (Assuming you are running a windows operating system)

```
python -m pip uninstall tensorflow
```

It may arise a conflict manifested as denied access. This is because of CONDA user access rights.
Go to C:/ProgramData, navigate to anaconda3. Find the sitepackage folder inside there. You will see previous installation folders and files inside the folder related to tensorflow. Remove the tensorboard, tensorflow, tensor_distribution, keras etc. all things associated with tensorflow from the folder.

Open up your conda-prompt - type in the command

```
conda clean --a
```

Wait for a bit. Type in the following commands, should be sequentially executed.

```
conda update conda
conda update --all
```

Restart Conda. Again install Tensorflow. This will resolve your problems.

P.S: I had the same problems. Now it is working fine.